# How to Make Card Header No Border Radius in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, border, bootstrap-4

How can make the card-header have no border radius on bootstrap 4? I've implemented this one BUT the background color of the card-header overlaps the card-header therefore the card-header still have border-radius

```
.card-header {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8h9mj7f8/ it's not having radious. Change if I made something wrong.

Comment: @AkiraSuzuki. I've seen it in the Bootstrap 4 default file. Why is it implemented in bootstrap 4? .card-header:first-child {
    border-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px) calc(.25rem - 1px) 0 0;
}

Comment: I think bootstrap support "card" class. If you dont like that, you can define "mycard" class.

Comment: I've just made it border-radius: 0 !important

Answer (score 10):

To remove the radius, specify a class **rounded-0**. Bootsrap 4.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-0">...</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

As you wrote in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316719/how-to-make-card-header-no-border-radius-in-bootstrap-4#comment79595436_46316719), Bootstrap adds `border-radius` to the `first-child` of `.card-header`.

I suggest, that this is in this case the background-color.

When you overwrite it, it should be solved:

```
.card-header:first-child {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzw8hop6/3/)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Try

```
.card, .card-header, .card-body, .card-footer{
    border-radius:0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
.card-header:first-child {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in SCSS

```
@if $enable-rounded == false {
  .card {
    .card-header {
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    .card-body {
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    .card-footer {
      border-radius: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

You will have to include the SCSS variable $enable-rounded before loading bootstrap SCSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <div class="card-tools">
              <select class="form-control" name="dropdown_media">
                      <option value="1">Active Media</option>
                      <option value="0">Blocked Media</option>
                      <option value="all_media">All Media</option>
              </select>

            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="card"><div class="card-header">...
```

You need to declare **border-radius: 0;** for both classes **card** & **card-header**

Comment: I tried doing this but it didn't help. The above suggestions worked.